# Is there some way to prevent any and all restarts? Not just from Windows Update?

Tags: windows-7, reboot, automatic-update

I am running a critical research program on a Windows 7 PC that needs to run uninterrupted for several months. I have had to re-initialize the entire experiment several time due to unexpected restart. Windows Update is disabled, and I have removed automatic updating from all background programs that have an option for it, but I am still getting restarts at random intervals that completely destroy my experiment.

Is there some way to prevent any and all restart requests?

Comment: Sounds like something is wrong with your PC.  Look at the logs for why it is restarting.

Comment: Thank you Keltari. I did look for errors in the log files, but found none. Also, there is no memory dump for this event. Is there a log file that records non-Microsoft updates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this to be effective, I would shut down any and all unnecessary services and programs unrelated to the experiment (such any AV or anti spyware programs as well as superfluous driver add on's or updaters). Is the experiment using the Internet? If not, disconnect it.

Additionally get a nice big UPS connected to the machine, one that is far bigger than necessary so it can withstand a power failure of a couple hours. Probably a 2000 VA or more. If the Internet is needed for the machine, go bigger on the UPS and hook up your ISPs modem and your router to it so the Internet stays up in the power outage as well.

Make sure all power saving features are disabled, including battery ones if you happen to hook the ups up to the computer via data cable as well.

Hope for the best of luck.

Comment: Im curious if you have a UPS at all at this point, even adding one that is the correct size for the load (half the maximum rating of the UPS) may help if the restarts are coming from power sags or some other kind of dirty power.

Comment: agree, my computer in xp or windows 7 on a desktop platform with UPS. The updates are done manually, running for a month or 2 at a time is not a problem. If it is a crash causing a restart, then turn off auto restart in the computer properties, so you get a blue screen instead. analise any programs or temperatures.  Ohh, and one more Check your Task Scheduler.  There are a few items in there reguarding stability and performace that MS uses to do checks. Not sure about the function of all of them, but doing a memory test, because it thinks there is a memory issue would need a restart.

Comment: Thank you @Paperlantern. I did not have a UPS attached to this machine! I will be installing one before I try anything else. I do have all power saving features disabled, as well as the power and reset panel buttons. As far as programs go, I do have an AV running (MSE), but I've gone through and removed all the other programs I could get rid of. I'll take another look to see if I can remove anything else. 

Psycogeek, thanks for pointing out the Task Scheduler, I don't have anything running in there but I hadn't checked before.