# Prevent Windows 10 from log off, restart, or shut down with open files/programs

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, shutdown, automatic-update

I'm looking for a group policy setting or a third-party program that can prevent Windows 10 (and earlier) from a logoff, restart, or shutdown command, initiated by either the user or the system.

I didn't have as many issues with this in Windows 7, however Windows 10 has automatically restarted my computer several times from updates in the middle of me working on something. I know other users have complained about this over the past several months as well. I have also accidentally logged off of my computer once or twice before while I have programs and files open, and it doesn't prompt to close programs or anything of that nature.

I would like to be able to totally prevent the system from logging off, restarting, or shutting down unless I manually close all of my open programs and files first. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

As a note, I've already set the local policy item under Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Shutdown Options for "Turn off automatic termination of applications that block or cancel shutdown" to "Enabled".

:::EDIT:::

I've seen this question: [Is there some way to prevent any and all restarts? Not just from Windows Update?](https://superuser.com/questions/375958/is-there-some-way-to-prevent-any-and-all-restarts-not-just-from-windows-update)

Unlike that question, I'm asking for a group policy setting (that I haven't already set) or a third-party program that will prevent Windows 10 (and earlier) from not only being shutdown or restarted, but also prevents a log off command. The question linked refers to no program or group policy that will suffice as an answer to my question.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I edited my post detailing the difference between my question and the one that you had linked to. Also though, one other item in my question that I would like to make apparent is that I only want to prevent a logoff, restart, or shutdown while there are open programs. If I close out of all of my open programs, only then should a logoff, restart, or shutdown command proceed. I hope this clears up the confusion.

Comment: Reopened. Please keep your comments to comments instead of adding them to the question.  I've reversed by close vote, but I can do nothing about your down votes, as I didn't add them.

Comment: Disconnect from any network so you don't get updates, use a higher tier version to push them back, don't use Windows 10. There shouldn't be a good scenario I can think of to prevent a log off and it probably would interfere with various system services as the SYSTEM user and similar constantly log on and off in the background. Otherwise there is a [plenthora](http://www.rizonesoft.com/disable-windows-10-updates-group-policies/) of articles describing the GPOs related to updates. Otherwise just reboot regularly (every other week) as Win 10 takes a while and only on serious updates it's forced.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks for reopening my question. I just edited the question as was indicated to include additional information from the prompt on the website.@Seth, I appreciate the response, however I don't feel that you understand my question fully. I only want to prevent a logoff/restart/shutdown while I have a program open - not entirely block updates or restarts. I just need something that will block an auto-restart or a restart/logoff/shutdown that I initiate on accident.

Comment: Hey Justin, I think the question is justified and your own answer fits. Feel free to select it as the right one!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I finally found a solution to this problem of mine. There's a third-party program called "Don't Sleep" (http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/DontSleep) which does exactly what I need it to do.

While running, it will prevent an inadvertent logoff, restart, or shutdown of the computer either via an automated Windows Update, a program prompting for a restart, or from a user error of mis-clicking one of the power options from the Windows Start Menu. To perform the power option you'd like, just close the program. "Don't Sleep" can be set to run automatically upon startup and can keep itself in the taskbar. Also, it's a portable program so there's no installation necessary.

I'm unsure of why my question got downvoted twice, but regardless I hope this can help anyone else who has a similar problem/question that I had.